# How do I add in a new template for my lift project (including url setups)?

Tags: templates, scala, url, lift

I just created a hello-world project with maven command in the book:

```
mvn archetype:generate -U \ 
-DarchetypeGroupId=net.liftweb \ 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=lift-archetype-blank \ 
-DarchetypeVersion=1.0 \ 
-DgroupId=demo.helloworld \ 
-DartifactId=helloworld \ 
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

And as instructed, I start it with:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

Everything works fine until the moment that I would like to add in another template besides:

```
my-project/src/main/webapp/index.html
```

For example, I put pricing page (pricing.html) just beside **index.html** to be "**my-project/src/main/webapp/pricing.html**". But the following url does not seem to work for me: **http://localhost:8080/pricing**

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it to Boot.scala:
http://simply.liftweb.net/index-3.2.html

Comment: I thought that in lift, template finding is automatic and derivative. No?

Comment: It does find the template automatically, but the location from which it's searching must be specified in SiteMap. Here's a page more specifically about SiteMap: http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/SiteMap Note that "[a]nything not listed in the SiteMap will (normally) not exist as part of the public-facing part of the app"